# If DFA has two states, which of the conditions hold?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Let $L$ be a regular language ,and $M = (Q, Σ, δ, q_0, A)$ is a DFA such that $L(M) = L$.
 Prove that if $|Q| = 2$ then one of the following holds :
a) $L=∅$ b) $ε∈L$ c) $∃a∈Σ$ and $a∈L$

The problem is, I think all of these are FALSE. If there is 2 states, none of them are accepting states, then L will have no elements. This disproves b) and c). However if one of the states is accepting, then a) is false !
I dont see how one of these statements is always true.

Comment: Without further restrictions, I agree with you

Comment: If none of the states is accepting, it’s case a. If the initial state is accepting, it’s case b. If the other state is accepting, it’s case c if the state is reachable, and case a otherwise.

Comment: At least one of the three statements will be true. But note that (b) and (c) can both be true at the same time.

Comment: Also note that "one of the following holds" means that at least one of the three statements is true for any given two-state DFA, but a different statement (or statements) may be true for different DFAs.

Comment: More generally, the proof of the pumping lemma shows that if a DFA with $n$ steps accepts some word, then it accepts a word whose length is shorter than $n$.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be misunderstanding the statement of the exercise. It wants you to show that if $L$ is a language accepted by a DFA containing two states, then either $L$ is empty, or $L$ contains the empty word, or $L$ contains a word of length 1. Which of the cases holds depends on $L$. More explicitly:

- If no state of the DFA is accepting, then $L = \emptyset$.
- If the initial state of the DFA is accepting, then $\epsilon \in L$.
- If the other state of the DFA is accepting, then either the state is reachable, in which case $\sigma \in L$ for some $\sigma \in \Sigma$, or else it is unreachable, in which case $L = \emptyset$.

More generally, the proof of the pumping lemma shows that if $L$ is accepted by a DFA containing $n$ states, then either $L = \emptyset$ or $L$ contains some word whose length is less than $n$. This is sharp, in the following sense: for each $n \geq 1$ and $m \in \{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, there is a language accepted by a DFA of length $n$ whose shortest word has length exactly $m$ (exercise).